# Requesting an html file with handlebars content in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, get, handlebars.js

First question so I hope my formatting works. I've got a node server running that works great. I'm writing a simple javascript file to get HTML files from this server that looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var request = require('request');

request.get("http://my.ip.address/htmlTemplate.html", function (error, response, body){
    if(!error){
        console.log(body);
        var x = body;
    }
});
```

and the HTML templates have Handlebars included in them, like so:

```
<!-- htmlTemplate.html -->

<div class="fake" id="thing1"></div>

{{#if foo}}
    <div class="conditional_html">
        All this stuff inside here.
    </div>
{{/if}}

<div class="{{bar}} class2" id="thing2"></div>
```

The request works and I receive the content, but the content I get back from the response is this:

```
<div class="fake" id="thing1"></div>


<div class=" class2" id="thing2"></div>
```

The handlebars content is omitted. I'd like to get the file in it's raw, uncompiled form (as plain text). Is this possible with an http request? Can I read this file remotely in way similar to `fs`?

Answer (score 0):

The Handlebars content isn't omitted. You haven't provided the value of `foo` in your request, so `if foo` returns `false`. Modifying the request url to something like `http://my.ip.address/htmlTemplate.html?foo=true` should make the conditional content get rendered in the final response.

As far as avoiding the rendering is concerned, it depends upon the configuration of the server which is processing the request (`http://my.ip.address` in your case). If all documents responses are behind a rendering engine (which is normally the case), you can't bypass the rendering. You can, however, selectively (manually) set certain routes to serve responses without compiling. Simply send the response without calling `Handlebars.compile()` or `template()`.